# Recommended RDF editor with clickable rdf:resource attribute values

Tags: xml, editor, rdf

I have RDF files written in CIM/XML. Is there any editor/viewer to recommend which is able to make internal links of rdf:resource attribute values?
For example:

```
<cim:Terminal rdf:ID="T1">
    <cim:Terminal.ConductingEquipment rdf:resource="#CE1"/>
    <cim:Terminal.ConnectivityNode rdf:resource="#CN1"/>
    <cim:IdentifiedObject.mRID>ID1</cim:IdentifiedObject.mRID>
</cim:Terminal>
```

I would like to be able to click on `#CE1` and be redirected to the node with a given `"rdf:ID=CE1"`.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the CimSpy to navigate into files RDF. Try it.